# JPA2 on Tomcat - possible?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, jpa-2.0, bean-validation

I'd like to use JPA along with Bean Validation, so JPA 2.0 sounds like what I need.  I'm running my web application on Tomcat 6. Is Tomcat able to use JPA2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You just need to place a JPA implementation (Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc) in `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: Great, thanks for the info.  It looks like my problem is that bean validation isn't working at all in my web app... I have the hibernate validator 4.1.0 libs in my WEB-INF folder, but it's not working on JPA or managed beans yet.